# How to generate iid sample from a given arbitrary probability density function

Tags: python, random

I want a function `randgen(f, N)` in python to generate N sample from a given pdf.

It's what I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def randgen(f,N, M=1):
    sample = M*np.random.random(N)
    y=[]
    sum = 0
    for x in sample:
      v = f(x);
      sum+=v;
      y.append(v)
    y = y/sum;
    return np.random.choice(sample, p=y, size=N)

def pp(x):
  return x**2

z = randgen(pp, 2000)
plt.hist(z)
```

It generates the following histogram for the function `y=x^2`. It seems working.

[image]

I have seen similar questions but without a clear reference to the function definition for `randgen(f,N)` which can takes arbitrary functions. I would like to know if my approach is correct or I missed a point.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, to unpack your solution:

- generate N random numbers between 0 and 1
- calculate a probability for each number depending on a given function
- rescale your solution so that the integral of that function is 1
- draw N numbers from your "generated" pdf

The way you did it definitely fulfills the criteria for a probability density function and your solution should be correct, but can improve it by using uniformly spaced numbers for the calcultation of your pdf.

numpy.linspace(start,stop,N) produces N evenly spaced numbers between start and stop. (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)

Your solution is fine for discrete pdfs if you apply my suggested addition instead of your 
sample = M*np.random.random(N) 
sample = np.linspace(start, stop, N)

edit: The pdf also has a requirement, that the probabilities have to be positive, so there should be some mechanisms included to avoid negative 
function values for x in range [0,1].

Comment: Thanks, however I and you draw N numbers from N numbers, I think the population must be much greater than N.

Comment: I dont think so, as long as you are okay with it being a discrete PDF it does not really matter. You can throw a six sided dice 20 times without the need of 20+ different results. If you really want a continuous pdf you have to rescale it differently. The only problem I see now is, that you can have negative "v" which should be handled, because that can not happen in a pdf.

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you please accept it or are there still problems for you? (I know its been a while^^)

Comment: As you said it's a while from my question and I can't test anything. According to my previous comments, it seems I wasn't completely satisfied with answer, however I voted your answer up. since it's important for future answerers and readers, I think we'd better to leave it as is. In general don't bother much about these virtual scores, and think about benefits of sites for all members.